# Dual of Schanuel's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow E \rightarrow K \rightarrow 0$ and $0
>  \rightarrow M \rightarrow E' \rightarrow K' \rightarrow 0$ be short
>   exact sequences with $M$ a left $R$-module and $E, E'$ injective left
>   R-modules. Prove the dual version of Schanuel’s Lemma by showing that
>   E ⊕ K′ $\cong$ E′ ⊕ K.

Two questions:

1. What is the dual of Schanuel's Lemma precisely?
2. How does "showing that E ⊕ K′ $\cong$ E′ ⊕ K" succeed in proving the dual of Schanuel's Lemma?

Comment: The dual of S's lemma is $E\oplus K'\cong E'\oplus K$.

Comment: What does it mean for a E, E' to be "injective left R-modules"? I thought that only functions could be injective.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module